# Compare words in two arrayList<String> java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, cpu-word, string-comparison

I've got two ArrayList of String and i want to count words that are in both of them.

Each ArrayList contains keyphrases, for example strings of few words like:

un'altra recessione

strada lunga

presidente barack obama

[...]

I tried with this two methods but i get a NullPointerException

```
 public boolean containsKeyword(String testKeyword, ArrayList<String> list) 
{ return list.contains(testKeyword);
}

public int compareKeywords(Quotidiano quotidiano){
    int sameKeywords=0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.Keywords.size(); i++){
            if(this.containsKeyword(this.getKeyword(i), quotidiano.Keywords))
             sameKeywords++;
          }

    return sameKeywords;
}
```

Thanks a lot for answers!

---

[EDIT]

It worked using intersection, thank you! 
But it would be better if it compares single words.

For example, if i have keyphrases

"spread of italy",

"spread under 300",

I think intersection is null, instead i would like "spread" returned.
How can I do it?

Comment: and can u please post the complete stack trace with code

Comment: add error/exception handling to avoid runtime errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Apache ListUtils Intersection](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#intersection%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29)

```
public static java.util.List intersection(java.util.List list1,
                                      java.util.List list2)
```

PS: This throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` - if either list is null

Comment: I guess OP wants to check all individual words within the 'keyphrases'.

Comment: It worked using intersection, thank you! But it would be better if it compares single words.

For example, if i have keyphrases

"spread of italy",

"spread under 300",

I think intersection is null, instead i would like "spread" returned. How can I do it?

Comment: For that you need to `split` the individual keyphrases. So "spread of italy" --> {"spread","of","italy"} and "spread under 300" --> {"spread","under","300"}. Then, `intersection` would yield "spread" as required.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for null whenever you are getting an input from unknown source. You should not count that the input is OK.

```
public boolean containsKeyword(String testKeyword, ArrayList<String> list) 
{ 
    return (list != null) ? list.contains(testKeyword) : false;
}

public int compareKeywords(Quotidiano quotidiano){
    if(quotidiano == null || this.Keywords == null) return 0;
    int sameKeywords=0;
     for(int i=0; i<this.Keywords.size(); i++){
        if(this.containsKeyword(this.getKeyword(i), quotidiano.Keywords))
         sameKeywords++;
    }

    return sameKeywords;
}
```

checking this.Keyword is optional as I assume that's your code and you are aware it should always be different then null.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` occurs when you are using member of any object and that object is not yet initialized. Make sure both the lists are initialized and are not null.